# Python 2D list to dictionary

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a 2 Dimensional list and have to get 2 columns from the 2D list and place the values from each column as key:value pairs.

Example:

```
table = [[15, 29, 6, 2],
        [16, 9, 8, 0],
        [7, 27, 16, 0]]

def averages(table, col, by):

    columns = tuple(([table[i][col] for i in range(len(table))]))  #Place col column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary
    groupby = tuple(([table[i][by] for i in range(len(table))]))   #Place groupby column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary

    avgdict = {}
    avgdict[groupby] = [columns]
    print(avgdict)

averages(table, 1, 3)
```

Output is:

```
{(2, 0, 0): [(29, 9, 27)]}
```

I am trying to get the output to equal:

```
{0:36, 2:29}
```

So essentially the 2 keys of 0 have their values added

I'm having a hard time understanding how to separate each key with their values
and then adding the values together if the keys are equal.

Edit: I'm only using Python Standard library, and not implementing numpy for this problem.

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear to me what you would like to achieve. Also not clear why the question is tagged with "machine-learning"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an empty dictionary, then iterate through every element of `groupby`. If the element in `groupby` exist in the dictionary, then add the corresponding element in `columns` to the values in the dictionary. Otherwise, add the element in `groupby` as key and the corresponding element in columns as `value`.The implementation is as follows:

```
table = [[15, 29, 6, 2],
    [16, 9, 8, 0],
    [7, 27, 16, 0]]

def averages(table, col, by):
    columns = tuple(([table[i][col] for i in range(len(table))]))  #Place col column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary
    groupby = tuple(([table[i][by] for i in range(len(table))]))   #Place groupby column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary

    avgdict = {}

    for x in range(len(groupby)):
        key = groupby[x]
        if key in avgdict:
            avgdict[key] += columns[x]
        else:
            avgdict[key] = columns[x]

    print(avgdict)

averages(table, 1, 3)
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep your initial avgdict, then you can change the `averages()` function to

```
def averages(table, col, by):
    columns = tuple(([table[i][col] for i in range(len(table))]))  #Place col column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary
    groupby = tuple(([table[i][by] for i in range(len(table))]))   #Place groupby column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary

    avgdict = {}
    avgdict[groupby] = [columns]

    newdict = {}

    for key in avgdict:
        for x in range(len(key)):
            if key[x] in newdict:
                newdict[key[x]] += avgdict[key][0][x]
            else:
                newdict[key[x]] = avgdict[key][0][x]

    print(newdict)
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a minute to figure out what you were trying to accomplish because your function and variable names reference averages but your output is a sum.

Based on your output, it seems you're trying to aggregate row values in a given column by a group in another column.

Here's a recommended solution (which likely could be reduced to a one-liner via list comprehension). This loops through the unique (using `set`) values (`b`) in your group by, creates a dictionary key (`agg_dict[b]`) for the group by being processed, and sums all rows in a given column (col) if the group by is being processed  `(table[i][by] == by`).

```
table = [[15, 29, 6, 2],
         [16, 9, 8, 0],
         [7, 27, 16, 0]]


def aggregate(tbl, col, by):
    agg_dict = {}
    for b in list(set([table[i][by] for i in range(len(table))]))
        agg_dict[b] = sum([table[i][col] for i in range(len(table)) if table[i][by] == b])
    print(agg_dict)


aggregate(table, 1, 3)
```

Comment: my apologies for making it unclear, i missnamed the function.

Comment: No problem. I was just trying to help clarify the ask. When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favorite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the following answer. It doesn't use `numpy`, and is based on the use of `sets` to find unique elements in `groupby`.

```
table = [[15, 29, 6, 2],
         [16, 9, 8, 0],
         [7, 27, 16, 0]]

def averages(table, col, by):
    columns = tuple(([table[i][col] for i in range(len(table))]))  #Place col column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary
    groupby = tuple(([table[i][by] for i in range(len(table))]))   #Place groupby column into tuple so it can be placed into dictionary

    '''groupby_unq: tuple data type 
                    stores list of unique entries in groupby.'''
    groupby_unq = tuple(set(groupby))

    '''avg: numpy.ndarray data type
            numpy array of zeros of same length as groupby_unq.'''        
    avg = np.zeros( len(groupby_unq) )

    for i in range(len(groupby)):
        for j in range(len(groupby_unq)):
            if(groupby[i]==groupby_unq[j]): avg[j]+=columns[i]

    avgdict = dict( (groupby_unq[i], avg[i]) for i in range(len(avg)) )

    return avgdict     

result = averages(table, 1, 3)
print result       

{0: 36.0, 2: 29.0}
```